# How can I get a tablename of a PostgreSQL cursor?

Tags: postgresql, database-cursor

I know that in Oracle we can do something like `select * from TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR('$$SQL_ID'))`. But there is no sql id field in `pg_cursors` catalog. We have only declaration text. And in general it's not Oracle. So, are there any ways to get a table name of an opened cursor in postgreSQL, besides parsing a sql statement(pg_cursors.statement)?

Comment: What do you need the tablename for?